# Facebook js api - "unsupported get request" error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to get some (I think allowed) information in my app. I have an access token that has the following info:

```
App ID: <my app id> : iHOUSEListingPoster - Test 001
Type:   User
App-Scoped User ID:   <user id> : Joe Webb
Valid:  True
Scopes: email, pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts, public_profile
```

I'm trying this:

```
FB.api( "/me",
        "GET",
        {fields: 'name'},
        function(get_fb_info_response) {
         console.log("Here: ", get_fb_info_response
      });
```

And getting this error:
"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation"

I have tried with both "/me" and "/me/". And while I want name, picture and email, I tried limiting it to just name, and still. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out what the problem is/was here (sheepish face). We have a couple of Facebook accounts here at the company. One is the container for my app  and it's test app, the other is a more general company account. I was logged into the general company account. When I tried my app, it grabbed some random app from that account, which wasn't the app that matched the access token (which I think is possible wrong on Facebook's part), therefore this error was thrown.

Once I logged into the correct Facebook account, all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name', function(response) {
    console.log('me', response);
});
```

I'm not sure if `api` function from `FB` does have this signature you're using.

## Edit

After searching at [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API/), found that the signature you were using is valid as well. Then, I went to do some tests here. And I was able to reproduce the same error you have mentioned when calling the function like this:

```
FB.api("/<123>/", "GET", { fields: 'name' }, function(response) {
    console.log('response', response);
});
```

To fix it, you need to remove < and >, for example:

```
FB.api("/123/", "GET", { fields: 'name' }, function(response) {
    console.log('response', response);
});
```

Calling `/me` and `/me/` endpoint returned no error in my test.

In this screenshot you can see the tests I have run directly at my browser's console.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried the variations, still getting: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation".   The chevrons weren't in my actual code, I just use them to surround my "fake" parameters.  I'm more confused because your code is working, and my pretty much identical code is not.  8-(

Comment: Ok, in the Graph Explorer, I tried "me?fields=name". The permissions, per the explorer, are:

email
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts
public_profile

And I get the exact same error. I'm baffled.

Comment: Well.. in that case it's probably a permission error.  Test your access_token at `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken` and check if you have the `public_profile` scope.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the access token, per the access token debugger, has
these permissions:

email

pages_show_list

pages_read_engagement

pages_manage_posts

public_profile

Comment: Ok, over the the Facebook Developers Group, it seems like the problem is that we need to get "Access Verification" as a "Tech Provider", cause nothing like forcing new hoops on existing apps/customers. I'll report back if doing this fixes the problem.

Comment: Have you checked if your app still in development mode? Usually in development mode you don't face those permissions errors.

Comment: The app has been in use in production for several years. I'm currently working on a "test" version of the app, so it is in development mode, and can't be made "Live". I'm trying to make sure that the app is up-to-date, because our clients are reporting errors using it more and more lately.

Comment: Ok, per all the documentation I have been able to find, we're not "up" for the Access Verification as 'Tech Provider' yet, so I have no way of doing that. I am left with the error "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation" and a pointer to the top level Graph documentation. Grr.

Comment: @leonardomdr, How to make a nice screenshot? The shadowed number red circle is good visualization for step order. Can you share this skill?

Comment: Hey @BenchVue, I use ShareX (https://getsharex.com/) with the multi region mode enabled.